# Save additional info to Facebook authenticated user?

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-socialauth

I'm using python-social-auth and I'm successfully able to authenticate a user with his Facebook account, but only the email is persisted. How do I:

1. persist the birthday?
2. add and persist information that doesn't come from FB, like his pet name? (as far as I know, I'll have to use a pipeline but don't know how)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

PS: Would someone with enough reputation create a tag 'python-socialauth'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Birthdate persistence is as simple as defining `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_EXTRA_DATA = [('birthdate', 'birthdate')]`, later you can access it by doing `user.social_auth.get(provider='facebook').extra_data['birthdate']`.

Other data must be saved with a pipeline, which is not as simple, but not hard to do. A pipeline is a function that will be called during the auth process (even on signup, login or association, so the function needs to check for that if needed). The function will get many parameters like the `strategy`, `backend`, `social`, `user`, `response`, `requests`, `details`, etc, it's best to define the needed parameters and then use `**kwargs` to ignore the others.

Once the function is coded, it should be added to `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` setting (be sure to add the default entries also, or the auth process won't work, those can be find here http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/pipeline.html#authentication-pipeline).

Comment: Should I add the pet name to the extra_data field, as long as it is a json formatted field? Would it cause me problems with python-social-auth?

Comment: I don't know if I made myself clear, but what I said was add the pet name using a pipeline funcion. Got it?

Comment: You can add anything you want to `extra_data`, also you can add anything into `details` in a pipeline function and also define the name in `_EXTRA_DATA` setting, and it will be stored too.